# I am getting 0 whenever I try to do division in SQL (how do I get around this)?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, select

I tried running this query (current_pop is the current population of the countries in my table):

```
select country, current_pop/8000000000
from countries
```

What I got was 0s . I'm pretty sure this is because I am dividing an integer type by an integer and so it wont give me a decimal number. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to workaround the integer division. Here, the simplest  approach is to turn the fixed operand to a decimal:

```
select country, current_pop/8000000000.0
from countries
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does integer division, so `1 /2 = 0`.
Multiply by `1.0` in any calculation where there are integers divided so SQLite will cast the numbers to real and perform division of real numbers:

```
select country, 1.0 * current_pop/8000000000
from countries
```